# webservice flow, proxy and soap address

Tags: web-services, soap, proxy, connection-timeout

I am very new to SOAP webservice. Want to know few things..
1. There is an URL (say, A) by which we can access the WSDL, then what the "soap:address" is used for. I have found a new IP address (say B) as "soap:address location" mentioned in WSDL but this URL is totally different from A. My question is why B address is needed - is this some internal IP address of a machine that resides behind A and completely unaccessible from client. What is the flow?

1. Since A is not public, so the host have given the access permission to my WAN IP so that I can access A. Now I can access the A url (getting a WSDL content) from simple Java code

   URL oracle = new URL(A);

   URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection(proxy);

as I am behind a proxy firewall. But I can access by

```
URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
```

From this can I conlude that Java by default tries to connect any URL bypassing machine's default proxy configuraion?

1. I have generated the client stub from WSDL URL and found that it is annotated with A

   @WebServiceClient(name = "BDCDataExchange", targetNamespace = "some url", wsdlLocation = "A"

But when I am running the code it is giving

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpClientTransport.getOutput(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(Unknown Source)
```

As I can access A from my simple java code, does this exception means that I can not access the internal soap:address B?

But the same client code is working if I generate the client using local WSDL path like

```
wsimport A   //not working while executing, above exception comes
wsimport <a local path where I saved the WSDL file>  //it works when I run
```